# What do you call someone who just assumes control?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I am writing a paper on a dystopia and how the leader came to be. I need a term to describe how he wasn't elected into power but he just assumed the role of instigator and no one questioned him.

Comment: Why not *tyrant*?

Comment: I am trying to make the leader look like an okay person

Comment: Could you give the sentence you would like to write but with a blank where the word should go? The extra context will help. Thanks.

Comment: So *usurper* wouldn't fit either. You probably need to incorporate that "okay-ness" into your question.

Comment: @bib *Tyrant* is defined by Oxford Dictionaries -online as *a cruel and oppressive ruler*. The mere fact that a leader is not elected does not necessarily make them a *tyrant*. And indeed, some who have been elected have turned out to be *tyrants*. (Hitler won power through the democratic process.) But I sense the OP is looking for the word for someone who showed some leadership qualities and others naturally followed him.

Comment: You could say that he is a "take-charge gentleman". This is generally considered a positive trait to have but I am not sure if it covers the scenario that "nobody questions him".

Comment: @WS2 If you look at ODO's definition 1.2, it also has the sense of seizing power without legal authority. But the modern connotation still is highly negative, so it doesn't suit OP's particular need.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal Or possibly a *take-charge lady*!

Comment: a **natural leader**

Comment: @WS2 OP used "....... **he** wasn't elected into power but **he** just assumed the role......" ! :P

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a standard single-word term, but Google Books claims [about 3,220 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22self-appointed%20leader%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for...

> ***self-appointed leader***

(There are a few hundred more for [*self-appointed **ruler***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22self-appointed%20leader%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22self-appointed%20ruler%22), for example.)

---

I don't think *self-appointed* necessarily and inherently carries negative connotations, but it's possible not everyone shares that view. So you might also consider...

> ***de facto*** - something generally accepted or agreed to without any formal decision in its favor:
>   *“They never elected him; he became their leader **de facto**.”* [<sub><sup>- dictionary.reference.com</sup></sub>](http://dictionary.reference.com/)
>    *“He is our **de facto** leader”*

Answer (score 0):

To describe a head of state (or another constituency) who wasn't elected but assumed office through sheer determination, charisma, trickery, demagoguery, assassination or war, I would say he *muscled his way to the top*.

Answer (score 0):

A **providential leader** may fit.

> Essentially the "providential leader" is an influent patriot that has the opportunity to do something for the country and that takes into account the 
>   concerns expressed by the people in charge and around to bring a better
>   contribution to its country.

Answer (score 0):

**"he naturally emerged as a leader"**

- His personality traits - actions and attitudes - were such that he naturally emerged as a leader.

**"he was a born-leader"**

All others were no match for him. He was a born-leader and rose to that post naturally, facing no opposition.

Answer (score -1):

There is a concept *[benevolent despotism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightened_absolutism)* (also called *enlightened despotism*) that suggests absolute power, but with a heart.

Associated with this term is a saying I have heard, but whose source I cannot find:

> *The best form of government is benevolent despotism -- so long as I get to pick the despot.*